# is there anyway to interpolate an array index into a BrowserRouter path?

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to show 2 seperate portfolio's when i click on a portfolio card and I have some nested data that im working with. I can access everything in the console with this:

mappedPortfolioNames[0].props.id

mappedPortfolioNames is a map of an Investor user.

Here is the entire component:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import StyledCard from '../styled_components/Card.style'
import PortfolioOfStock from './PortfolioOfStock'
import CardParent from '../styled_components/CardParent.style'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { UserContext } from '../context/UserContext'

const ListOfPortfolios = ({portfolios}) => {
  const navigate=useNavigate()
  const {investor
        } =useContext(UserContext)

  // const mappedPortfolioId = portfolios.map(portfolioId => (
  //   portfolioId.id
  //   )
  // )


  console.log(portfolios[0].id)

  const goToPortfolioClick = e  => {
    console.log('ello')
    navigate(`/current-portfolio/${portfolios.id}/` )
  } 

  const mappedPortfolioNames = portfolios.map( p => (
    <StyledCard 
      key ={p.id}
      id = {p.id}
      onClick={goToPortfolioClick}>  
      Portfolio: {p.id} <br/>
      {p.portfolio_name}
    </StyledCard>

    )
  ) 
console.log(mappedPortfolioNames[0].props.id)


  return (
    <CardParent >
     
      {mappedPortfolioNames}
    </CardParent>

  )
}

export default ListOfPortfolios
```

I was expecting to try and render a list of stocks within a portfolio by clicking on a portfolio card. I can navigate away from the portfolio cards, but I cant figure out how to interpolate that particular portfolio. This is a many-to-many relationship within my rails DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `portfolios.id` which would be undefined since `portfolios` is an array of objects. You should pass the ID of the clicked portfolio to the URL:

```
const goToPortfolioClick = (id) => {
  navigate(`/current-portfolio/${id}`)
}
```

Then update `mappedPortfolioNames` as follows:

```
const mappedPortfolioNames = portfolios.map( p => (
  <StyledCard 
    key={p.id}
    id={p.id}
    onClick={() => goToPortfolioClick(p.id)}>  
    Portfolio: {p.id} <br/>
    {p.portfolio_name}
  </StyledCard>
))
```